# parsing of string using regex in perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, parsing

```
DESCR: "10GE SR"
```

i need match this above part which is part of my rest of the string. Im using regex in perl. 
i tried

```
if ($line =~ /DESCR: \"([a-zA-Z0-9)\"/) { 
   print "$1\n";
}
```

but im not able to understand how to consider spaces inside my string. these spaces can occur any where within the quotes. can someone help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = 'DESCR: "10GE SR"';

if ($str =~ /DESCR: \"([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)\"/) { 
    print "$1\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look, this pattern can match double quoted in string:

```
if ($line =~ /DESCR: \"((?:[^\\"]|\\.)*)\"/) { 
   print "$1\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler:

```
if ( $line =~ /DESCR: "([^"]+)"/ ) { 
   print "$1\n";
}
```